# Removing default camera movement in SimpleApplication

Tags: xamarin.android, urhosharp

I'm absolute beginner in UrhoSharp. I only wanted to implement some basic 3D stuff into my app. Everything works fine with SimpleApplication, the screen is supposed to be watched from one place and direction. **When I touch the screen, the scene rotates however. How can I get rid of this behavior?**

I wanted to try to override some function of SimpleApplication (probably OnUpdate) so I came with name CursedApplication replacing SimpleApplication everywhere. When I use

```
using CursedApplication = Urho.SimpleApplication;
```

everything still works. But what I supposed to be the equivalent

```
class CursedApplication : Urho.SimpleApplication
{
    CursedApplication(ApplicationOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

breaks the application. Some idea how can I make things work? Or do I have to build my own scene logic without SimpleApplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that this can be done with

```
app.Input.Enabled=false;
```

where app is instance of SimpleApplication.